# route everything except 123.123.* through vpn

Tags: linux, vpn, iptables, openvpn, route

I would like to route all requests to 123.123.* normally through eth0 and everything else through VPN (tap0).

This should probably be done with iptables. Any ideas how?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with route.

```
route add -net 123.123.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev eth0
route add default gw 10.8.0.1
```

Assuming the gateway on your VPN network is 10.8.0.1

Comment: great. that also means dns resolving is being done through gateway?

I am asking this because some (not all) subdomains from the 123.123.* cannot be found if try access them in firefox. I just get host not found. but if I "host subdomain" it resolves the right IP.

I have this in my resolv.conf (if 10.8.0.1) is vpn:
10.8.0.1 # vpn
123.123.1.1
123.123.1.2

Comment: "host subdomain" also does not resolve. that was wrong information. ideas? but if "host subdomain" is working from the gateway (it is a publicly accessible subdomain).

Comment: This doesn't change the behaviour of your DNS. The servers listed in resolv.conf will be queried in the order they're listed.

Comment: I improved your answer a little bit and now is everything OK:
1. route del default
2. route add -net 123.123.0.0/16 gw <my current gw> eth0
3. route add default gw <my new gw>

thanks.